# PDF loaded within UIWebView only shows first page

Tags: ios, pdf, uiwebview

We have a View that is just a `UIWebView` and some navigation buttons.  When you click on a link in the `UIWebView` that opens a PDF, it loads the PDF appropriately, and I can see the (Page 1 of X) where X is the number of pages in the PDF.  So the PDF is fully loaded, but it is stuck on the first page.  I can even scroll the page that is displayed up so I can see the second page, but it only allows me to go the standard "bounce" distance on the scrollview.

I looked at a problem with similar symptoms ([showing a pdf in uiwebview on ios9 sometimes scrolling is stuck](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35579248/showing-a-pdf-in-uiwebview-on-ios9-sometimes-scrolling-is-stuck)), but I don't load the about:blank page first, and the fix of trying to load a blank PDF did not fix our issue.  Is anyone else experiencing this issue?

Of note this seems to only be affecting iOS 9 devices.

Comment: I have exactly the same problem. It's fine on iOS 8, but PDFs won't scroll on iOS 9. I did fix the scrolling by removing
    webView.ScalesPageToFit = true
but then zooming stopped working. Have you found any solution?

Comment: Unfortunately no.  I think our issue has something to do with the fact that the website is trying to open the pdf in a new window.  It's a low priority for us right now, so we don't have a fix for it yet and haven't had much time to dig into it.

Comment: I changed to using WKWebView in the end which doesn't have the same problem

Comment: OK, I'll have to give that a shot and see if it fixes our issues. Ours seems to be doing some extra javascript that is contributing to it, but maybe WKWebView can handle it better.

Comment: Where you able to get this to work? I'm having the exact same problem but with WKWebView.

Comment: Because this was only iOS 9, we just lived with the issue as adoption increased. Unfortunately we never investigated and got to the root cause. It was definitely related to the JavaScript we were using around the PDF opening.